# How to use `split` on 2 Kleisli Arrows

Tags: scalaz

Here is a function: (T) => \/[E,U]

I can turn functions of this type into a Kleisli

```
def kleisli[E,T,U](c: T => \/[E,U]) = Kleisli[({type λ[+α] = \/[E, α]})#λ, T, U](c)
```

This allows me to compose and flatMap, combining the functions.

```
   val positive = (t: Int) => if (t > 0) \/-(t) else -\/("Negative")
   val even = (t: Int) => if (t % 2 == 0) \/-(t) else -\/("Odd")
   val evenAndPositive = kleisli(positive) >=> kleisli(even)
```

OK, nice.  I have recently come accross the functions in [ArrowOps](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/2bb418257cc6c55d288990943d6a5242d9ba6424/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/ArrowSyntax.scala#L5) and defined for Kleisli in [KleisliArrow](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/2bb418257cc6c55d288990943d6a5242d9ba6424/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Kleisli.scala#L309%20KleisliArrow).  I am specifically interested in split (***) but I can't quite figure out how to use it.  It looks as if it is an operation on two Kleisli, the same as >==>:

```
val eventAndPositive2 = kleisli(positive) *** kleisli(event)
```

However, that always fails:

```
   error: could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Unapply2[scalaz.Arrow,scalaz.Kleisli[[+α]scalaz.\/[String,α],Int,Int]]
       val eventAndPositive2 = kleisli(positive) *** kleisli(event)
```

How does one go about defining Unapply2 or is there a different way to use split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Kleisli` only forms an `Arrow` when the return type constructor forms a `Monad`. `String \/ A` forms a Monad, but because `\/` is kind `*,* -> *` and `Monad` requires a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, scala has trouble finding the `Monad` instance.  If you help it out, by creating a type alias which has kind `* -> *` it will find the `Monad` instance, and therefore the Arrow instance:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

object Main {
  type Err[A] = String\/A
  def kleisli[T,U](c: T => \/[String,U]) = Kleisli[Err, T, U](c)

  val positive = (t: Int) => if (t > 0) \/-(t) else -\/("Negative")
  val even = (t: Int) => if (t % 2 == 0) \/-(t) else -\/("Odd")

  val evenAndPositive = kleisli(positive) >=> kleisli(even)
  val eventAndPositive2 = kleisli(positive) *** kleisli(even)

}
```